# Root Can't Delete Folder It Owns

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, root

Platform: `CentOS 6.2` Shell: `tcsh`

---

**EDIT**
Brian Swift has pointed out a workable solution.  He points out that if the home directory is served via NFS, `root` on a client may not have the same permissions.  Logging in as `root` on the NFS server, the folder delete without complaint.  That still leaves me with some unanswered questions, though.

Background:

1. I created this file as `root` appr. 2 years ago on the same client I
   tried the below commands on.
2. All other `root` folders created on
   that same client from that same time period (mid-2010) deleted
   without complaint.

Questions:

1. What makes that folder a special snowflake versus the other client `root` created folders in my home dir?
2. Is there any way to check for deviant NFS permissions?

Again I owe Brian a big thanks for getting to the bottom of this, he is truly a super user!

---

**ORIGINAL Question:**

I'm lost as to what in the world is going on here... `root` owns this locked directory (from a manual `gcc-4.4.3` install) in my home directory.  I change to root (`su root`, also tried `su`) and try to delete it and get permissions errors.  I try to change the permissions, the operation is denied.  I try to `lsattr`/`chattr` it and get ioctl errors in the terminal.

---

To be clear, I'm doing general cleanup on my home directory, and I've been able to remove any other files I've wanted just fine with some help from `root` to hack through permissions barriers, etc.  It's just this one folder that's giving grief.

Here's what I've tried....

COMMAND:

```
whoami
```

OUTPUT

```
root
```

COMMAND:

```
 rm -rf gcc-4.4.3_objdir
```

OUTPUT

```
> gcc-4.4.3_objdir rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/config.status': Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': Permission denied rm:
    > cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/intl/config.status': Permission denied
    > rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/intl/config.intl': Permission
    > denied rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/intl/config.cache':
    > Permission denied rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/intl/Makefile':
    > Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/intl/config.log': Permission denied rm: cannot
    > remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/intl/config.h': Permission denied rm: cannot
    > remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/decNumber.o': Permission denied
    > rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/gstdint.h':
    > Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/config.status': Permission denied rm:
    > cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/decimal128.o': Permission
    > denied rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/decimal32.o':
    > Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/decContext.o': Permission denied rm:
    > cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/bid2dpd_dpd2bid.o':
    > Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/host-ieee64.o': Permission denied rm:
    > cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/decimal64.o': Permission
    > denied rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/config.cache':
    > Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/host-ieee32.o': Permission denied rm:
    > cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/host-ieee128.o':
    > Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/Makefile': Permission denied rm: cannot
    > remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a': Permission
    > denied rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/config.log':
    > Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/stamp-h1': Permission denied rm: cannot
    > remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber/config.h': Permission denied rm:
    > cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/build/errors.o': Permission denied
    > rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/cstamp-h': Permission denied
    > rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/objc': Permission denied rm:
    > cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/config.status': Permission denied
    > rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/gthr-default.h': Permission
    > denied rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/options.h': Permission
    > denied rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/gccbug': Permission
    > denied rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/ada/Makefile':
    > Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/ada/gcc-interface/Makefile': Permission denied
    > rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/cs-bconfig.h': Permission
    > denied rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/tmp-modes.h':
    > Permission denied rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/java':
    > Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/auto-host.h': Permission denied rm: cannot
    > remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/doc': Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/bconfig.h': Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/.gdbinit': Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/tm.h': Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/objcp': Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/as': Permission denied rm: cannot remove
    > `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/config.cache': Permission denied rm: cannot
    > remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/optionlist': Permission denied rm: cannot
    > remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/configargs.h': Permission denied rm:
    > cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/s-options': Permission denied rm:
    > cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/Make-hooks': Permission denied rm:
    > cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/s-options-h': Permission denied
    > rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/Makefile': Permission denied
    > rm: cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/cp': Permission denied rm:
    > cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/collect-ld': Permission denied rm:
    > cannot remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/nm': Permission denied rm: cannot
    > remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/config.log': Permission denied rm: cannot
    > remove `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/config.h': Permission denied rm: cannot
    ...
```

COMMAND:

```
ls -laFd gcc-4.4.3_objdir
```

OUTPUT

```
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root 4096 Mar 19  2010 gcc-4.4.3_objdir/
```

COMMAND:

```
id
```

OUTPUT

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:###########
```

COMMAND:

```
chown -R root:root gcc-4.4.3_objdir
```

OUTPUT

```
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/build': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/cstamp-h': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/objc': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/config.status': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/gthr-default.h': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/options.h': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/gccbug': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/ada/Makefile': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/ada/gcc-interface/Makefile': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc/ada/gcc-interface': Operation not permitted
...
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libiberty': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/fixopts.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/config.status': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/fixinc.sh': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/fixincl.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/mkheaders.almost': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/mkheaders': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/fixincl': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/server.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/fixlib.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/fixtests.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/procopen.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/full-stamp': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/Makefile': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/config.log': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/stamp-h': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/config.h': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes/fixfixes.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/fixincludes': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/config.cache': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/stage_final': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/stage_current': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/Makefile': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/config.status': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/line-map.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/lex.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/identifiers.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/symtab.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/mkdeps.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/makedepend': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/pch.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/localedir.h': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/directives.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/config.cache': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/makedepend.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/localedir.hs': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/traditional.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/init.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/charset.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/Makefile': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/libcpp.a': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/directives-only.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/errors.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/makedepend.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/pch.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/charset.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/line-map.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/mkdeps.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/symtab.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/files.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/directives-only.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/directives.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/expr.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/init.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/identifiers.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/lex.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/traditional.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps/macro.Po': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/.deps': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/macro.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/config.log': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/expr.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/stamp-h1': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/files.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/config.h': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp/errors.o': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/stage_last': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir/config.log': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `gcc-4.4.3_objdir': Operation not permitted
```

COMMAND:

```
stat gcc-4.4.3_objdir
```

OUTPUT

```
  File: `gcc-4.4.3_objdir'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 8192   directory
Device: 1ch/28d Inode: 36835590    Links: 10
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2012-04-24 04:04:17.251456720 -0400
Modify: 2010-03-19 18:23:51.000000000 -0400
Change: 2012-04-20 12:02:38.334456000 -0400
```

COMMAND:

```
chattr -i gcc-4.4.3_objdir
```

OUTPUT

```
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir
```

COMMAND:

```
lsattr gcc-4.4.3_objdir
```

OUTPUT

```
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/config.status
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/intl
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libdecnumber
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/gcc
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/serdep.tmp
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libiberty
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/zlib
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/build-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/stage_final
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/stage_current
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/Makefile
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/libcpp
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/stage_last
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on gcc-4.4.3_objdir/config.log
```

Comment: Just a random guess: this is a readonly filesystem because of some leaf mount or so. Check the output of "mount".

Comment: @GregoryMOUSSAT Results of `mount gcc-4.4.3_objdir`: `mount: can't find gcc-4.4.3_objdir in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`; Results of `mount` `/dev/mapper/vg_<MACH_NAME>-lv_root on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,rootcontext="system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0")
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw)
/dev/mapper/vg_<MACH_NAME>-lv_home on /home type ext4 (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
<CENSORED HOME>`

Comment: @GregoryMOUSSAT The dir does not appear to be in the list of mounted directories, and attempting to mount it (not sure why you would do that, but I wasn't sure if you meant to do that or just get the `mount` listing) does not work either.

Comment: Might make sense if directory was coming from a NFS server or some other form of NAS. Depending on server config, root on client might not be able to delete files, and server might not support file attributes.

Comment: @BrianSwift Interesting hypothesis...
Home is on an NFS server... I'm gonna try to delete it on there.  Typically though, root can delete anything in my home directory on a client, so this is an odd exception.  Any idea why there'd be a special exception for a specific folder on a client and/or how to check that?

Comment: HA what do you know, that worked!  Can you make that an answer? I'll upvote you and check you.  Also, if you have any insight into how one lone folder can be disallowed for deletion on clients, vs. every other folder, that would be much appreciated.  To clear up one possibility I thought up, the folder was NOT created on the NFS server machine.  It was created by `root` on the same (client) machine I'm currently on.  (Anything else created by root on my NFS client machine has proved perfectly delete-able by `root`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might make sense if directory was coming from a NFS server or some other form of NAS. Depending on server config, root on client might not be able to delete files, and server might not support file attributes.

As to why only this directory had problems, I'll just speculate that the NFS configuration (or NFS client or server software) changed in some relevant manner sometime after the directory was created. I would have been curious if `ls -l` showed on the server ownership was `root`, your username, or `nobody`.

One additional speculation, if this directory was created by un-taring a gcc distribution as root, maybe the directory picked up some funky ownership/permissions from the tar archive, rather than directories and files you created directly.

Comment: Thanks again! (the ownership on the server was `root`, the same as on the `client`... fwiw)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the directory with your own account?

When deleting a file or directory you are in fact modifying the parent directory fo that file (everything is a file in linux even a directory).  And you have the permissions to modify your home directory.

Another thing to check is SELinux, run `/usr/sbin/getenforce`, if it says "Enforcing" you can either try to disable SELinux temporarily `/usr/sbin/setenforce 0` or check the SElinux settings `ls -lZ gcc-4.4.3_objdir` and use `/sbin/restorecon -R /home/<username>/` to correct them.

Comment: Interesting theory... sadly switching to `permissive` via `echo 0 >/selinux/enforce` (I verified `permissive` was in effect.) did nothing ... still got the same `Permission denied` errors.

Answer (score 0):

This should delete that file or folder:

```
chmod -Rf 777 your_folder_or_file_name

rm -rf your_folder_or_file_name
```